# Preserve clipboard contents after application quits

Tags: linux, qt, pyqt, clipboard

This question has been asked here numerous times, but I couldn't find any instance of it that has actually been answered. Consider the following simple scenario:

- Run a PyQt5 application with a `QPlainTextEdit` (let's say, on latest Ubuntu)
- Enter some text, then copy it using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
- Quit Application

The expected behavior is that the text is still in the clipboard, however it's gone. All the answers to this question describe that this is how things work in Linux without a clipboard manager installed.

This is not entirely true though - as explained on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence):

> Gnome settings daemon, the component of Ubuntu that handles all
>   copying and pasting by default, conforms by allowing applications to
>   explicitly request to save their clipboard contents in a safe place.
>   Applications conform by requesting a save before they exit. Everything
>   gets squared away before a quit and we don't lose any data

[There's even a solution provided for GTK applications](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-store):

> `gtk_clipboard_store ()`
>
> Stores the current clipboard data somewhere so that it will stay
>   around after the application has quit.

Is there any Qt (PyQt) equivalent of this method?

Comment: The clipboard will only be persistent if another SW uses it, and some OS's have a clipboard manager that does that job but that's not in all cases. There have already been several such posts and the same conclusion was reached.

Comment: I don't agree with that - there is software that makes it persistent and I have even pasted a description of it. There's a GTK+ call to use it and it works in GTK+ applications. I am not able to find such a call in Qt and that's what the question is about.

Comment: If you will be able to find a question that actually provides information about equivalent Qt call, then I'll agree that's a duplicate. Right now it's not, as every answer includes generic description how X11 clipboards work.